Is a transformation linear if it preserves linear relations?
We know the definition of a Linear transformation, which satisfies the following equality:
$$\displaystyle f(c_{1}\mathbf {u} _{1}+\cdots +c_{n}\mathbf {u} _{n})=c_{1}f(\mathbf {u} _{1})+\cdots +c_{n}f(\mathbf {u} _{n})$$
This shows that a linear transformation preserves linear combination and, consequently, linear relation.
My question is: If a transformation preserves linear relations, can we conclude that it is a linear transformation? In other words, does the preservation of linear relations imply that the transformation satisfies the properties of linearity?
Edit 1
In the context of a linear relation, when we say a transformation $f$ preserves linear relations, we mean that:
$$(\sum c_i u_i = 0 \ \land \prod c_i \not=0) \Rightarrow \exists \left\{c'_i\right\} : (\sum c'_i f(u_i) = 0 \ \land \prod c'_i \not=0) $$
Note in particular that the coefficients $\left\{c_i\right\}$ may not be the same as $\left\{c'_i\right\}$. That is, the transformation may map the vectors to a different set of coefficients, but still preserve the structure of the linear relation.

What about $f=0?$

@GreginGre $f=0$ is linear

Edited answer (the statement is still correct, but the arguments were wrong).
No, this is not an equivalence: Take for example $\mathbb R$ as the underlying vector space (over the field $\mathbb R$). Then any bijective map $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ which maps $0$ to $0$ preserves linear relations:
If for some $c_i$ and $u_i$ we have
$$\sum c_i u_i=0 \text{ and } \prod c_i \ne 0,$$
there are three options:
either all $u_i$ are zero, in which case also $f(u_i)=0$ and the statement is clear.
Or there is exactly one $u_{i_0}\ne 0$ and the other $u_i$ are zero, which would imply $c_{i_0}=0$ and would violate $\prod c_i \ne 0$. Therefore, this case does not occur.
If at least two $u_i,u_j$ are not equal to zero, then you can choose $c_k' =1$ for all indices but $k=i$ and $k=j$. Then choose $c_j' \ne 0$ in a way that $\sum_{k \ne i} c_kf(u_k) \ne 0$ (which is always possible because $f(u_j) \ne 0$) and choose $c_i' = \frac{-1}{f(u_i)} \sum_{k \ne i} c_k'f(u_k)$.
This shows that for example $f(x)=x^3$ preserves linear relations but is not linear.

if $\prod c_i \neq 0$ then how can we have a case where $c_{i_0} = 0$? same with the third case where you take $c'_k = 0$, doesn't that violate the $\prod c'_i \neq 0$ condition?

@MihirKekkar you are absolutely right. I fixed the arguments. My statement remains correct, though.
